# is it mandatory to give a table an alias or there are cases i should give?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT ic FROM sd
WHERE ic <= (SELECT ic FROM md WHERE
sd.ic = md.ic);
```

Should i give the table sd an alias for this query to work ?

Comment: Not necessary in this case, this should work with or without Alias. Every `derived` table must have an alias, other than that its not always a `must`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever we use joins we always use alias its a good practice but in subquery its not neccessary its up to condition that we use in subquery.
If we use joins between 3 to 4 tables we always use alias because we can remember the name and can write easily.

Answer (score 1):

It's not mandatory but it's a good practice. In a more complex query you will loose yourself with more than 4-5 tables with raw names.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the inner query using JOIN operation . Also if there is multiple values for the result this wont work